# mat-expansion-panel remove border

Tags: html, angular, css, angular-material

I have a mat-data-table with mat-expansion-panel as a column. For some reason on some rows the mat-expansion-panel has a border around it, how do I get rid of that. When the user hovers the mouse the expansion panel expands and when the mouse leaves it collapses. The data that those rows have, they are just as same as the ones without borders. Here in this picture its the notes column that has the mat-expansion-panel inside the mat cell.
[image]

```
 <mat-cell *matCellDef="let workOrder">
                    <mat-expansion-panel class="" _ngcontent-c0="" ng-reflect-hide-toggle="true" #panel *ngIf="workOrder.notes !== ''" hideToggle="true"
                        (mouseenter)="panel.open()" (mouseleave)="panel.close()">
                        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                            <mat-panel-title style="justify-content: center">
                                <mat-icon style="color:#8fbbdf;">notes</mat-icon>
                            </mat-panel-title>
                        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
                        <mat-panel-description>
                            {{ workOrder.notes }}
                        </mat-panel-description>
                    </mat-expansion-panel>
                </mat-cell>
```

Comment: i can't inspect which inheritance is giving this border to your math-expansion-panel. Simply inspect it and apply the same css selector with border:none; at the bottom of your css file (that should be loaded after the one that is causing the border).

Comment: @JoelBonetR I tried that it didn't work. If there is a border setting there it should apply to every row where there is a note, but this happens only to a few of them.

Comment: Select only notes so to apply CSS... Need a working code to help

Comment: Thanks @JoelBonetR I am not sure what happened, right now I dont see a border, will get back to if the issue returns.

Comment: @JoelBonetR, the same issue is back. I tried .mat-expansion-panel-header {
  border:none;
}, it didn't work. I have updated my original post with a pic that is from the Chromes inspector.

Comment: On Chrome inspect.. look at your right, click on Computed tab. Search for all border properties and upload this pic top. Thanks

Comment: I got the pic of the computer tab added. check it out. I do see one with 1px which border-image-width, I tried putting that to none, it didn't work. mat-expansion-panel-header {
    border-image-width: none;
  }

Comment: Border-image-width doesn't work with "none", have you tried with Border-image-width: 0, or Border-image-width: 0px;?

Comment: Anyway  the border-image-width is dependant of border, so if you ser border:none it should be non applicable too

Comment: Tried putting the border-image-width to 0px as well, didn't work. Just wondering why it happens to only some rows.

Comment: Can't you provide the necessary code snippet to reproduce this behaviour?

Comment: Here in this example it is the weight column with the expansion panel in it and that is the same issue that I am having right now, want to get rid of that border. Check it out  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iubspg-pxib8z

Comment: lol, i can't see any computed border but it's shown. What a strange behaviour...

Comment: Yeah that's right

Comment: The most i could do is to isolate the issue. The mat-expansion-panel-header seems to be the one causing this, check your classes around it or whatever js are doing on it, hope it helps

Comment: I checked almost everything can't seem to find anything that would do this.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be on mat-expansion-panel tag. If i remove all classes of it, the border disappear so it might be an "issue" on some class of it or with the combination of more than one. 
i changed from:

```
<mat-expansion-panel _ngcontent-c0="" class="mat-expansion-panel ng-tns-c3-1 ng-star-inserted" hidetoggle="true" ng-reflect-hide-toggle="true">
```

to:

```
<mat-expansion-panel _ngcontent-c0="" class="" hidetoggle="true" ng-reflect-hide-toggle="true">
```

on the **first** element and this is the result (the desired one, i think):
[image]

Working fine when expanded too:
[image]
Hope it helps you

Comment: I tried doing what you said, it didn't make any effect. I have updated the original post. check it out with the code.

Comment: Its the same as before, it still has a border.

Comment: And the mat-expansion-panel has no classes or something is inserting some on it?

Comment: mat-expansion-panel has no classes, I dont think anything is inserting anything there.

Comment: please, clear your browser cache. i can't see any border now. Cheers!

Comment: Tried on chrome, chrome canary and edge.

Comment: Not sure, I cleared the cache, tested it on firefox and chrome. it is still there.

Comment: Maybe i have to think about putting some other way, eliminating the expansion panel.

Comment: Maybe... But it could be nice to clarify the isse too

Comment: I wish, i like the way it expands, but what to do, have been trying for a week now.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the prompt responses on getting this thing fixed. Appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome :) let's see if someone faces the same issue

Answer (score 0):

override the mat-expansion-panel display property like: mat-expansion-panel style="display: unset;"

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue as well and I solved it by setting the `background-color` on `mat-expansion-panel` to be the same background-color as the rest of the content. In my case I set it to `white`.

The reason you couldn't inspect this in the devtools is because it's not a real border element yet it gets an appearance as one due to its similar sizing.